# Speeding up nested Django ORM queries

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I'm using the handy [Django sessions library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-user-sessions) in my Django project. This allows me to process Session objects via ORM queries.

The attributes I can access for each Session object are:

```
    Column     |           Type           | Modifiers 
---------------+--------------------------+-----------
 session_key   | character varying(40)    | not null
 session_data  | text                     | not null
 expire_date   | timestamp with time zone | not null
 user_id       | integer                  | 
 user_agent    | character varying(200)   | not null
 last_activity | timestamp with time zone | not null
 ip            | inet                     | not null
```

Where `user_id` is from the Django `User` model.

Using the Session library, I need to find the number of users in my app who currently don't have an entry in the Session table (and their corresponding `IDs`).

I tried it via the following:

```
logged_in_users = set(Session.objects.values_list('user_id',flat=True))
logged_in_users = [user_pk for user_pk in logged_in_users if user_pk is not None]
logged_out_users = set(User.objects.exclude(id__in=logged_in_users).values_list('id',flat=True))
num_logged_out = len(logged_out_users) #passed to template to display
```

My Session table contains **1.7M** rows, whereas the User table contains **408K** rows. The code above take an abnormally large amount of processing time (i.e. several minutes), and ultimately gives me a 500 error in production (works correctly on limited data sets in development).

Before trouble shooting what went wrong, I feel I also ought to optimize the query to get the result less expensively.

What are some obvious optimizations you feel my code needs? I know I can find the number of `logged_out_users` by subtracting the number of `logged_in_users` from `total_users`. But what about getting all their IDs?

Comment: Is `user_id` a `ForeignKey` to the `User` model or just an integer?

Comment: It's a FK. The table definition includes `Foreign-key constraints:
    "user_id_refs_id_898fa0fe" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[UPDATE]**: After some discussion in the comments, the question asked about retrieving (and counting) the `id`s of the logged out `User`s (i.e users that don't have an entry in the `Session` table at all).

So:

```
# Get a (flat) list of user ids where the user entry in not null
logged_in_users = Session.objects.filter(user__isnull=False).values_list('user__id', flat=True).distinct()

# Get a (flat) list of user ids excluding the previous logged ones (thus, this list will contain the logged out users)
logged_out_users = User.objects.exclude(id__in=logged_in_users).values_list('id', flat=True).distinct()

# Count the logged out users
logged_out_users_count = logged_out_users.count()
```

How about this:

```
# Fetch all user_id values from the Session table where the user ForeignKey has
# no value (thus, it's null)
null_user_ids = Session.objects.filter(user__isnull=True).values_list('user__id', flat=True)

# Count the null users
no_of_users = null_user_ids.count()
```

Comment: Updated. Did this clarify for you? You asked *users who currently don't have an entry in the Session table*. This means that the `user` entry is `null`.

Comment: So isn't that filtering the Session table for rows where the fk `user` is `None`? Unauthorized users create entries in the Session table with `user_id = None`

Comment: Yes. Well not exactly `None`, but database speaking it's `null`.

Comment: So there could be users in the `User` table who don't have an entry in the `Session` table at all (e.g. they logged out). Would those be captured by this?

Comment: Since they don't have an entry in the `Session` table and the above query "scans" the `Session` table, then these users will not show up in the results.

Comment: Yep. So those are the users I need. Essentially, I need all users who don't have an entry in the Session table (i.e. logged out).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138660/discussion-between-nik-m-and-hassan-baig).